# SSH alerts for outside IP addresses

Tags: ssh, login, monitoring

So i have a script that emails me if a login is from anything besides an ip address that starts with "10.1.":

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib, os

server = "10.10.10.10"
From =  "address1@example.com"
to = ["address2@example.com"] # must be a list
subject = "SSH Login from outside network"

ip = os.environ['SSH_CONNECTION'].split()[0]
user = os.environ['USER']


if '10.1.' in ip:
    print "---SSH IP Check---"
    print 'Inside address, no alert will be sent.'
    exit(0)


text = user + " just logged in from " + ip

# Prepare actual message
message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (From, ", ".join(to), subject, text)

# Send the mail
server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
server.sendmail(From, to, message)
server.quit()
```

I've added this to .bashrc for /root/.bashrc and when i login as root to this remote server, this runs, checks the $SSH_CONNECTION variable and emails if it doesn't start with 10.1.

But what if someone logs in as user? or another username?
I originally had a file /etc/ssh/sshrc which i think is a bash script(no #!/bin/sh on first line though) and it worked ok, but i wanted a check of the ip so thats why i did this in python, in bash it didnt like the double [[ brackets, and i was just piping it out to sendmail.

So the question is how can i make this script run on any ssh login? should i keep trying with the sshrc file?

I've tried replacing the sshrc file with this python script, but i get this when i log in:

```
/etc/ssh/sshrc: 3: /etc/ssh/sshrc: import: not found
/etc/ssh/sshrc: 5: /etc/ssh/sshrc: server: not found
/etc/ssh/sshrc: 6: /etc/ssh/sshrc: From: not found
/etc/ssh/sshrc: 7: /etc/ssh/sshrc: to: not found
/etc/ssh/sshrc: 8: /etc/ssh/sshrc: subject: not found
/etc/ssh/sshrc: 10: /etc/ssh/sshrc: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: That file was a key-value configuration file, not a script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have the script triggered when a login session is opened.

**[pam-script](http://pam-script.sourceforge.net/)** is a PAM module that allows you to execute scripts within the PAM stack during authorization, password changes, and on session opening or closing.

In Debian-based Linux distributions it is provided by the `libpam-script` package. In Fedora the package is simply called `pam-script`.

The following scripts can be triggered by pam-script:

- `pam_script_auth` - executed during authentication
- `pam_script_acct` - invoked during account management
- `pam_script_passwd` - invoked when changing passwords
- `pam_script_ses_open` - invoked when session is opened
- `pam_script_ses_close` - invoked when a session is closed

To run a script on session open add this to `/etc/pam.d/common-session`:

```
# Attempt to run pam_script_ses_open and pam_script_ses_close.
# Report success even if script is not found.
session optional pam_script.so onerr=success
```

In Debian, by default, pam-script will execute `/usr/share/libpam-script/pam_script_ses_open`. The location of the scripts can be configured with the `dir=/path/to/scripts/` option.

With pam-script it is also convenient to access the IP address of the remote host in a bash script. Each script will be passed the following environment variables (all will exist but some may be null if not applicable):

- `PAM_SERVICE` - the application that's invoking the PAM stack
- `PAM_TYPE`    - the module-type (e.g. auth,account,session,password)
- `PAM_USER`    - the user being authenticated into
- `PAM_RUSER`   - the remote user, the user invoking the application
- `PAM_RHOST`   - remote host
- `PAM_TTY`     - the controlling tty
- `PAM_AUTHTOK` - password in readable text

Answer (score 0):

**Slack Setup**

So first you would need to configure an Incoming Web Hook in Slack:

`https://YOUR_DOMAIN.slack.com/apps/manage/custom-integrations`

Configuring this will give you a Webhook URL to which you can post your messages.
**Machine Setup**

Now connect to your machine and create a script in your ssh folder:

`sudo nano /etc/ssh/notify.sh`

Add the following code to the script which we'll configure to run each time a user signs in:

**SSH SLACK alerts for outside IP addresses**

i have a script that emails me if a login is from anything besides an ip address.

Add the following code to the script which we'll configure to run each time a user signs in:

`sudo nano /etc/ssh/notify.sh`

```
if [ "$PAM_RHOST" != "10.0.4.61" -a "$PAM_TYPE" != "close_session" ] && \
[ "$PAM_RHOST" != "10.0.4.62" -a "$PAM_TYPE" != "close_session" ] && \
[ "$PAM_RHOST" != "10.0.4.63" -a "$PAM_TYPE" != "close_session" ] && \
[ "$PAM_RHOST" != "110.0.4.64" -a "$PAM_TYPE" != "close_session" ]; then
url="https://hooks.slack.com/ser..."
channel="#ssh-login"
host="`hostname`"
content="\"attachments\": [ { \"mrkdwn_in\": [\"text\", \"fallback\"], \"fallback\": \"SSH login: $PAM_USER connected to \`$host\`\", \"text\": \"SSH login to \`$host\`\", \"fields\": [ { \"title\": \"User\", \"value\": \"$PAM_USER\", \"short\": true }, { \"title\": \"IP Address\", \"value\": \"$PAM_RHOST\", \"short\": true } ], \"color\": \"#F35A00\" } ]"
curl -X POST --data-urlencode "payload={\"channel\": \"$channel\", \"mrkdwn\": true, \"username\": \"ssh-bot\", $content, \"icon_emoji\": \":computer:\"}" $url
fi"
```

Now make the script executable:

`sudo chmod +x /etc/ssh/notify.sh`

Finally add the following line to /etc/pam.d/sshd:

`session optional pam_exec.so seteuid /etc/ssh/notify.sh`
Done